# Extracting coordinates from FeatureCollection to add to Dictionary as values

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to recreate [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui_widgets) `ui.Select` function with data from an imported `FeatureCollection`.

In the original example the `ui.Select` function uses a dictionary that looks like this:

```
var places = {
  MTV: [-122.0849, 37.3887],
  PEK: [116.4056, 39.9097],
  ZRH: [8.536, 47.376]
};
```

So I would like to recreate with my own FeatureCollection. My attempt at code for creating the dictionary.

```
function get_coords(f){return f.centroid()}

var urban_areas = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(boroughs.aggregate_array('lad17nm'), 
                                          ee.List(boroughs.map(get_coords)));
print (urban_areas)
```

My code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/117c19c3958b28dba0b3f6e644680836).

Comment: It would be helpful, if you'd isolate your problem into a separate File, with the Feature Collection to transform. I can't find boroughs in ur Code

Comment: @AlexanderVocaet I have made the Feature Collection public, hopefully that works.

Answer (score 1):

I made a 'toy' example to illustrate a possible solution.

```js
var selector = ui.Select({placeholder:'fetching data..'})

var test_dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(['one', 'two'], [[0, 0], [1, 1]])

// Async fetch
test_dict.evaluate(function(dict){
  selector.items().reset(Object.keys(dict))
  selector.onChange(function(key){
    // make your process with value
    var value = dict[key]
    print(value)
  })
  selector.setPlaceholder('Select item..')
})

Map.add(selector)
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b183e792df540d4b4c9fbcc8b9a57b2b